# GoogleMaps Autocomplete (Places API)

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-nearby, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to fetch airports using the Places API autocomplete feature.

Looking at the `types` parameter, if this is an airport I display the result or else show it as **no airports found**.

I want to enhance this app, I want to show terminals within each Airport object that I display on the front end.

I have found the [nearby search within places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#opennow) but it is difficult to create a search query using `keyword`, and `type` to get exact results for all the airports around the world.

Does anyone have any idea as to what would be the best way to get airports and their terminals using the Places API?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to fetch airports around the world all at once?

Comment: No so on autocomplete api when someone searches for example "dublin airport" the airport location is returned with their terminal information

Comment: I would rather find a dedicated API or use a local database.

Comment: Yeah we are going ahead using our own database

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not sure if this is really your expected result but here's what I tried:

1. Get the `placeId` of an airport using Place Autocomplete.

   `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=dublin&radius=500&types=airport&key=API_KEY`
2. Then use that `placeId` to do a Place Details request and get the `coordinates` of the airport.

   `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJLxmTab4RZ0gRVfMlt7UbElU&key=API_KEY`

   This also returns an `overview` of the airport wherein in this case the result says: "

> *"Airport with 2 runways, a 2nd terminal opened in 2010 plus buses into Dublin & other towns/cities."*

3. Then after having the `coordinates`, I use that to do a Nearby Search request.

   `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?keyword=terminal&location=53.42644809999999,-6.249909799999999&radius=10000&key=API_KEY`

This managed to get the terminals around it, I just threw in some radius but I guess it should be different on other locations. I also tried this with other Airports and it somehow worked.

If this won't work for your use case. Another thing I think you could do is to store the coordinates of known airports (Please note that coordinates/placeID are the only thing that is allowed for us to store/cache. Please see [Specific Terms](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms/#:%7E:text=3.4-,Caching,-.%20Customer%20can%20temporarily)). And create an object which also stores the coordinate of their corresponding terminals. This would be an extensive work if you want to do this with airports all around the world.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very good answer, possibly improved by replacing radius=10000 with rankby=distance in the Nearby Search request. Note that airport terminals are buildings (types:["premise"]) which is not a supported search type in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table1 so the only way to find them using Nearby Search is using the keyword parameter and YMMV when using this approach.

Comment: Really appreciate your additional insight on this one @miguev. Thanks!